# Разрешить индексировать содержимое файлов на этом диске в дополнение к свойствам файла (Windows)

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-11

Что означает пункт в свойствах диска "Разрешить индексировать содержимое файлов на этом диске в дополнение к свойствам файла"?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В Windows есть индексация, как я понимаю, имен файлов, их расположений в файловой системе и свойств, например размера файла, тегов mp3 (исполнитель, альбом и т.д).

Настройка "Разрешить индексировать содержимое файлов на этом диске в дополнение к свойствам файла" добавляет к индексированию еще и содержимое файла?

Если эту настройку отключить, то индексировани будет работать как и прежде но без содержимого файлов?

Comment: Ну вы все верно написали. Вы хотите от нас подтверждения того, что написано в диалоговом окне?

Comment: @insolor В сети, сколько не гуглил, не нашел конкретного подтверждения, что это именно так. В основном говорят, что эта настройка отключает индексировани полностью. И странно, что настройки индексирования разнесены, что-то в свойствах диска, что-то в настройках поиска и т.д
Вообщем довольно не очевидно.

Comment: Ну в смысле, прямо по названиям пунктов все понятно. Что вам не очевидно? Почему в свойствах диска - потому что индекс занимает место, индексирование занимает время, особенно для медленных дисков - поэтому имеет смысл настраивать отдельно для каждого диска.